# How to make the Datatype indicator at the right of a TextField disappeared when clicking the left or right arrow keys?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield

There is a `TextField` populated by a value from a `RecordStore` , and the `carret` position is at 0 when `navigating` to the `TextField`. I need to go to a certain character position within the TextField's text. But when I click the right navigational `button` or when I press a character `key` then something like a `tooltip` with a text `Abc` is displayed automatically at the right of the `TextField`.

So how to make this "Abc" disappear ?
Here is a captured image of the situation:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution : I added this code `setInputModeOrder(new String[]{"Abc"});`

Comment: good, accept your own answer for future views of the question